# Can I "translate" static URL's?

Tags: templating, localization

I'm wondering if there's some build in function in Craft that can "translate" a URL the same as a string?

For example when I want to translate a static string I'll use the "t" Twig filer like so:

```
{{ "String"|t }}
```

Let's say I want to do the same, but with my localized URL's. Imaging this:

```
{{ url('a-url-slug')|t }}
```

Then in my translation file I can add different URL's that's localized (but loading the same template, I'm solving this using Routes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good idea, but it does work. You simply got the syntax wrong, it should be:

```
{{ url('a-url-slug'|t) }}
```

Comment: Would you look at that. Wicked! I want to avoid having to run multiple IF-statements in my template for different URL's for different static localized links.

Comment: What about using macro or do it with a plugin? But can't you just avoid using static links at all and make all these URL become entries, that's what I would try to do, @naboovalley!

Comment: Naa.. for example I have a button "Sign up" which is just inserted a little here and there in my templates. "/signup" for English and "/registrera-dig" for Swedish to keep SEO intact. Since I'm also translating the name of the button translating the link as well seems like a good approach. No? If I add a third language I can just update the translation-file.